# tcsh shell invokes csh script calls Makefile: Argument with double quotes and a space

Tags: makefile, arguments, csh, tcsh

I have a csh script that I call in a tcsh shell. The csh calls a Makefile. I'd like to either hardcode or pass in an argument `A_B_C="YYY ZZZ"` which goes to the Makefile. I have tried to simplify the problem with a toy example below.

So if the csh script is `run-csh` I would call in my tcsh shell:
`run-csh -option A_B_C="YYY ZZZ"`
which would then look like this in `run-csh`:
`(cd foo ; $command > a.log) &`

which should invoke (target `test` is hardcoded into `run-csh`):
`cd foo ; make test A_B_C="YYY ZZZ" D=E F=G H=J > b.log`

It appears the problem is the double quotes and space are getting dropped so it runs:
`make test A_B_C=YYY ZZZ`
and complains that ZZZ is not a valid make target

How can I either fix this argument on the tcsh command line (`-option A_B_C="YYY ZZZ"`) or hardcode it into the csh script (`A_B_C="YYY ZZZ"`)? If I skip the csh file and run `make test A_B_C="YYY ZZZ"` from tcsh, then everything works, so that is why I think it is the translation of the double quotes and space that is the problem. When I use echo in the csh script it appears exactly how I want it.

Comment: `make` always runs the commands with `sh`, so yes, the `sh` is dropping the double quotes before `csh` gets to see it.  Try using `A_B_C='"YYY ZZZ"'` (wrapping single quotes around the double quotes, or you can reverse the wrapping and use double quotes around single quotes).

Comment: From tcsh command line my flow (which might include scripts other than Makefile) had similar problems with `A_B_C='"YYY ZZZ"'` and `A_B_C="YYY ZZZ"`, but is working with `A_B_C='YYY ZZZ'`, which it translates to `A_B_C=YYY\ ZZZ`. Would I need to escape the slash in the csh script?

Comment: Succinctly: I'm not sure -- and you can experiment and find out.